# How to get language value when using setLocale() function?

Tags: java, android

I have `setLocale` function like below that I wrote in main.java file.

How can I get the current `Locale` in the `setLocale` function?

I use the `Locale` value to be able to include an "if-else" condition in another java file. This mean, I have 2 tables of data, when the language in `setLocale` function is English, I will select the table for English, and when I choose another language, I will select the table for that language.

```
// main.java
public void setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
    finish();
    startActivity(refresh);
}
```

Comment: `getResources().getConfiguration().locale` will have the value you are looking for.

Comment: Using like that, how will it return so I can apply it to the if function?

Comment: Sorry I understand slow. I use Locale.getDefault() so how can I have a comparison with a string for example the result of Locale.getDefault() is en, how do I assign it to a condition like if ( Locale.getDefault () == "en") { //function execution }

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, using language as a parameter to determine what to do is unstable, but you can still do it.  Using Annamalai Palanikumar's method above, you can do the following:

```
if (getLocale().getLanguage().equals(new Locale("en").getLanguage())) {
   // do something here
}
```

I hope this points you in the right direction.  Good luck!

Comment: I have error with " Cannot resolve method 'getLocale' in 'sqldata' "

Comment: `(Locale.getDefault().equals(new Locale("en").getLanguage())` i tried like this but not working is my statement correct?

Comment: Try (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals(Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage())

Comment: It still not working :(

Comment: Are you on an emulator?  Is your phone in the English Language?  I copied and pasted the code from my comment and it worked on a phone.

Comment: I use my phone, I set it to active, not passive, meaning when I click select a language, the app will switch to that language, is not using the system default language

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a new method to return the selected locale like the one below. and use this method in another java file.

```
public Locale getLocale() {
    return getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
}
```

Comment: I go to the if function to call the getLocale function from the Main.java file so the code will be if(Main.getLocale() == "en"), is that correct or not?